# How to make group of radio buttons (generated dynamically) work independently?

Tags: html

What I intend to do is to make each radio button group work independetly.
Please refer this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tkqew

I want to select an option from each line, but it is selecting only one option.

In future work I want to generate this whole icon thread dynamically so please if you could suggest how I can do that.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CmzLf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radio button group is created by specifying the same `name` attribute for the radio buttons in a group. Simply give another common `name` for the radio buttons in the second line so that they'll act as a different group...

Comment: But in future the list may be very long. Because it will be generated dynamically. So this would not be ideal solution

Comment: Well, you must be looping through some data for creating these.. use the index of the loop to produce common groups.. or provide a small scale example for **future** scenario so that we can come up with something related..

Comment: @user2043331 you can use a `index` like: every time you create a group just do `i++`.

Answer (score 1):

Radio Button activity relies on the names. If you want a group of Radiobuttons just name the group.

```
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" class="optionsRadios2" value="option1"  checked="checked" title="Nenhum">
{...}

<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" class="optionsRadios2" value="option1"  checked="checked" title="Nenhum">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using loops to creating those radio buttons, use the index (as a prefix) in the radio button name.

Like:

```
<input type="radio" name="first_1">
<input type="radio" name="first_2">
```

1 and 2 is the index here..

Answer (score 0):

You can select more then one option in radio button but dont put the radio button name same as other button, every button should have unique name.
like this

```
    <input type="radio" name="button1">
    <input type="radio" name="button2">
```

also visit your [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iCAdp) i have changed it

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each "set" of radio buttons distinct names:

```
<div class="icon-thread">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios_set1" class="optionsRadios2" value="option1"  checked="checked" title="Nenhum">
            <label class="radio" for="optionsRadios2"><i class="icon-ban-circle icon-stack-base text-error"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios_set1" class="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
            <label class="radio" for="optionsRadios2"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-moon"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios_set1" class="optionsRadios2" value="option3">
            <label class="radio" for="optionsRadios2"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-plane"></i></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="icon-thread">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios_set2" class="optionsRadios2" value="option1"  checked="checked" title="Nenhum">
            <label class="radio" for="optionsRadios2"><i class="icon-ban-circle icon-stack-base text-error"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios_set2" class="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
            <label class="radio" for="optionsRadios2"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-moon"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios_set2" class="optionsRadios2" value="option3">
            <label class="radio" for="optionsRadios2"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-plane"></i></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Edit: as an aside, you've misused the `for` attribute in the label. That should match the `id` of the `input` element.